# Chamisha Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-five?

### ?חמישה ושבעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 275.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred seventy-four entries in this ongoing series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

275 is the number of Jews on the island of Zakynthos during the Holocaust, all of which survived due to the [heroism of the mayor and the bishop](http://www.ushmm.org/museum/exhibit/online/greece/nonflash/eng/zakyntho.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There are 275 *parashiyos* in the *Tora*, [according to *Korach*](http://kodesh.snunit.k12.il/tan/b0038.htm/#2).